# ksoftirqd's bottom-halves in interrupt or process context?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

I have been meticulously reading the book named Linux Kernel Development written by Robert Love.

In my understanding, softirqs and tasklets are run in the interrupt context. Also, **ksoftirqd** is a kernel thread which runs in the process context. So, I find it quite puzzling and difficult to think how ksoftirqd (**process context**) is employed in order to run softirqs (**interrupt context**).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which context are softirq and tasklet in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135915/which-context-are-softirq-and-tasklet-in)

Comment: @harmic That question does not have an answer for `ksoftirqd`'s context.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar question on my mind while reading the book, here is a link which should clarify some things: [refer to this papar](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~nahum/w6998/papers/2003-wilcox-softirq.pdf)

> "ksoftirqd is implemented as a set of threads, each of which is
>   constrained to only run on a specific CPU. They are scheduled (at a
>   very high priority) by the normal task scheduler. This implementation
>   has the advantage that the time spent executing the bottom halves is
>   accounted to a system task. It is thus possible for the user to see
>   that the machine is overloaded with interrupt processing, and maybe
>   take remedial action.
>
> Although the work is now being done in process context rather than
>   bottom half context, ksoftirqd sets up an environment identical to
>   that found in bottom half context. Specifically, it executes the
>   softirq handlers with local interrupts enabled and bottom halves
>   disabled locally. Code which runs as a bottom half does not need to
>   change for ksoftirqd to run it."